# How to secure access to restricted pages using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, restriction, before-filter

I want to restrict the access to some pages to only logged users.

Those pages have an attribute `area = restricted``

So in my controller i am restricting the access as following:

```
before_action find_page # Where we instantiate @page
before_action authenticate_user! only: [:show], :if => :restricted? , :unless => :logged_in?
```

and farther in the controller i have

```
def restricted?
  @page.area == "restricted" ? true : false
end

def logged_in?
  current_user ? true : false
end
```

But for some reason, it didn't work...

Do you see something obvious in the code ?

Thanks !

UPDATE:

I simplified the code above by mixing the 2 conditions into one method as following:

```
before_action find_page # Where we instantiate @page
before_action authenticate_user!, only: [:show], :if => :must_be_authenticated
```

And my method us defined as following

```
def must_be_authenticated
  puts "must_be_athenticated call"
  return false if @page.area != "restricted" # If the area is not restricted no need for athentication
  return false if user_signed_in? # If user is signed_in no need for athentication
  return true 
end
```

The problem persists, and even the string "must_be_athenticated call" is not written in the log. So it seems that the `before_action :authenticate_user!, :if => :must_be_authenticated`is just ignored since no print out in the log of the debug string, neither the page is restricted...

UPDATE:

The show method is defined as following:

```
def show
  authorize! :show, @page
  render template: "pages/show"
end
```

Comment: Where are you instantiating @page?  Also, double check the ordering of :if/:unless.  If it were me, I'd move that current_user check into :restricted? and drop the :unless.  Just makes my head hurt to have both like that.

Comment: @page is instantiated in a before_action in the beginning of the controller. I'll edit my question for enhanced clarity.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion. But i could see already in the version of the code i have, that :restricted? is not even called ( i put some printouts in the method that never showed up in the log )

Comment: devise provides user_signed_in? so you could use it instead define your logged_in? method

Comment: I'm using it now(user_signed_in?).. Thanks !

Comment: Which particular controller contains `before_action` calls? What page are you requesting for to check if `before_action` works? Are you completely sure that `before_action` is written in the same controller which action gets evaluated?

Comment: They are in the same controller which is pages_controller. Even the must_be_authenticated method is within the controller ( No use of concerns or heritage of some kind ). Moreover, there is no heritage from the pages_controller and  it is the one handling the request. @page is well set also because it gets displayed with a theme reserved to restricted area... I'm puzzled!!!

Comment: Could you also provide source code of your `show` action and some output from logfile containing info about your request (starting with the URL of page being asked for) ?

Comment: Just an FYI, you don't need a ternary statement if you're returning true or false. For example, you only need `@page.area == "restricted"`.

Comment: Sorry guys for the delay! I updated my question...